# App can still get data via Microsoft Graph API after user revoke permission from My Apps Portal

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Steps:

1. Authorize 3rd party app with my Microsoft Account
2. Revoke app's permission from My Apps Portal
3. Go to the 3rd party app, the app can still use the access token to get data via Microsoft Graph API until the access token expires. Because when access token is expired, it would fail to refresh token.

So before access token is expired, the app can still get data even user revoke the permission.

Expert:

Reject app's request when user revoke the permission

Or

Have some methods for app to know whether user has revoked the permission

Comment: I tried on my side. If you revoke app's permission and the access_token acquired before revoking doesn't expire, you can still use it to get data. Your revoking will work for the token that you get new after revoking.

Comment: The before access token only has the unrevoked permission, so if you want to check the token, it couldn't show the new permission, unless you use the before refresh token to acquire a new access token.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behavior. Access tokens issued by Azure AD are currently valid until they expire. Revoking consent will prevent the application from being able to obtain *new* access tokens.