# Unauthorised application able to get the access of users in Azure Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, postman, azure-ad-graph-api

We have register new app in Azure AD use clientid and client secret to login and check other user details but now we removed all permission for the clientid and check using postman as well as from application,but its still login to app and able to get the other users details using **https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users** for users and **[https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BtenantId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/token)**  for token. Question is how user is getting the access when all permission already revoked?

Answer (score 1):

Even you revoked all permissions, please try resetting the **signInSessionsValidFromDateTime** user property to **`current date-time`**.

This must be performed by **user** or **administrator**.

By doing this, it deletes all the ***session cookies*** stored in user's browser that removes all the ***refresh tokens*** issued to application for a user.

Please ensure to have ***User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All*** permissions.

To ***revoke sign-in sessions from Microsoft graph explorer***, try using the below query,

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/revokeSignInSessions     (Or) 

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/revokeSignInSessions
```

[image]

> **After calling revokeSignInSessions, there might be a small delay of a few minutes before tokens are revoked.**

Please find below links if they are helpful.

**References:**

[user: revokeSignInSessions - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-revokesigninsessions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[App can still get data via Microsoft Graph API after user revoke permission from My Apps Portal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53165150/app-can-still-get-data-via-microsoft-graph-api-after-user-revoke-permission-from)

Comment: I was even able to get the data in POSTMAN with new token.